# MVC Update data in an Index View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I have an index view listing a bunch of information, example:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OptIn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Donation)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Attended)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Add One", "Check", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-default" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I want to set up an ADD ONE button here.  Notice the line above that says:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Add One", "Check", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-default" })
</td>
```

This is easy If I go to another controller/view however I want to stay in the index view.  I built a CHECK controller action result as follows:

```
public ActionResult Check(int? id)
//[Bind(Include = "ID, Attended")] 
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Guest guest = db.Guests.Find(id);
    guest.Attended = (guest.Attended + 1);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(guest).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Edit/" + id);
}
```

This is not working.  The page doesn't crash, but it is not doing anything.  I am guessing maybe I need to use JQUERY for this?  I havent learned JQUERY yet so I'm trying to avoid that.  Has anyone accomplished something like this before?  I think I'm on the right track but I am stuck at this point....

Comment: were you using jQuery before, if yes then check if you use `e.preventDefault()` or `e.stopPropagation()` on any of anchor click. Also, has it been updating ?

Comment: Your question was clear until you introduce CHECK controller. What is the purpose of CHECK controller. I think all you want to do is, adding a button which onclick should allow user to add a new item. The page should not refresh. Is that correct?

Comment: `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is a bit pointless - the only property in `ModelState` is `int? id` which can never be invalid.

Comment: What exactly is not working. The current code shows you increment the `Attended` property by `1` and redirect back to the `Index()` method. What are you expecting?

Comment: The attended field is not incrementing by one everytime I press the Add one button

Comment: Odd, I noticed that once i set the attend field to a number (it was Blank before) now it is working, incrementing by one.  I thought if it was blank the app would assume it was zero. I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure JQuery library is added then create script like :
    $(window).load(function () {
                 var data = $('#yourInputId').val();

```
               $.ajax({
                url: "http://" + location.host + "/CTRL/ACTION", 
                type: "POST",  
                data: { 'deleteId': data },
            }).done(function (data) {
                your logic here if server;
            }).fail(function (err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what your problem is exactly. Updating data in an Index view is easy - especially if you use a partial view. From the information that you have given here you do not need to use Jquery. But going through your controller I noticed this (which looks wrong):

`RedirectToAction("Edit/" + id);`

This is right:

`RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id});`